Angular 17 custom guard not working in combination with backend axios request
I'm currently developing an Angular application which has a protected page. I'm protecting the page by using a custom guard:
{
  path       : 'intern', // For testing purposes (internal page)
  component  : InternalComponent,
  canActivate: [loggedInGuard],
}

This is my login guard:
export const loggedInGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state): Promise<boolean> => {
  const loginService = inject(LoginService);
  const router       = inject(Router);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    loginService.isLoggedIn().then((isLoggedIn) => {
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        router.navigate(['/anmelden'], {queryParams: {redirect_to: state.url}}).then(() => {
          resolve(false);
        });
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
};

Inside the guard, I need to check if the user is logged in using my service:
public async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey);
  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    // await axios.post(this.verifyLoginUri, {token});
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    this.logout();
    return false;
  }
}

First, I check if the token returned and set during login is still set inside the local storage. If yes, I use the token to make a backend request using axios to check if the token in still inside my Redis DB. If no, I return a 401 error, which is processed by the catch block. If it's still inside the DB, I return 200.
The thing is that somehow my guard seems to ignore the request to the backend totally. When I comment in the axios request again, the protected page has no content. If I comment it out, the content is there depending on the local storage entry.
What am I doing wrong here? I mean, this is a logic use case. Every service validates the session inside the backend. Otherwise, some smart guy can just set the local storage entry and enjoy the internal page.

Try converting the promise to an observable.
public isLoggedIn(): any {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey);
  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    return from(axios.post(this.verifyLoginUri, {token})).pipe(
        map((response:any)=> {
           return true;
        })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    this.logout();
    return false;
  }
}

